# WD My Book NAS dont mount

Tags: networking, mount, hard-drive, nautilus, raid

I updated to Ubuntu 19.04 recently.
I had a Western Digital Book World edition NAS connected ( with 2 HDD, 1TB each, in RAID configuration) on my local network and ubuntu 18.10 could see and i was able to access the data through the file manager ( Nautilus I think).
Now I get an "error resolving "BookWE.local":Nae or service not known"

Could any one please tell how to fix?

Comment: Please post the exact message. "Nae or service not known" is probably "Name or service not known". If so ...could it be you forgot to add the DNS of the NAS to the system?

Comment: Hi, Yes the complete message is : < error resolving "BookWE.local":Name or service not Known >. Is it handy to tell me how to add the DNS of the NAS to y system?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2998/how-do-i-mount-a-wd-mybook-world-network-drive-in-linux

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it.